# "else" statement keeps triggering upon updating Firebase user's name?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication

I have a pop up modal which appears when the user clicks on "update profile" from the dropdown nav menu. In this modal, they can change their username.

I am trying to implement the following workflow: user clicks "update profile", types in their new username, clicks the "submit" button, the form resets and the modal closes.

The first username update works exactly as I want. Subsequent update attempts seem to trigger my "else" statement, which is to catch if the user left the new username field empty, and triggers a window alert.

Here is the code for my entire update profile modal:

```
const updateProfileModal = (currentUser) => {

    // DOM Elements
    const modal = document.querySelector(".modal");
    const openModalButton = document.querySelector("#update-profile-btn");
    const updateButton = document.querySelector("#update");
    const updateProfileForm = document.querySelector(".profile-update-form");
    const profileNameField = document.querySelector("#profile_name");
    const closeModalButton = document.querySelector("#close-modal");

    // Open "update profile" modal when clicked from dropdown menu
    openModalButton.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();

        // Hide the dropdown menu after opening update profile modal
        document.querySelector(".dropdown-content").classList.toggle("show");

        // Show user's email address and current username in placeholders
        document.querySelector("#profile_email").placeholder = currentUser.email;
        document.querySelector("#profile_name").placeholder = currentUser.displayName;

        // If the modal doesn't have the CSS "show" class:
        if (!modal.classList.contains("show")) {

            // Toggle that class into the modal
            modal.classList.toggle("show");

            // Upon clicking on "update" button inside modal:
            updateButton.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
                e.preventDefault();

                // Get value of new displayName
                const newName = profileNameField.value;

                // Update displayName.
                if (newName !== "") {
                    updateUsername(newName)
                    updateProfileForm.reset();
                    modal.classList.toggle("show")
                    firebase.auth().currentUser.reload();
                } else {
                    window.alert("Must choose a new name to update")
                }
            })
        }
    })

    // Close profile updating modal upon clicking the "x"
    closeModalButton.addEventListener("click", () => {
        modal.classList.toggle("show");
    })
}
```

Here is the updateUsername function which it uses:

```
// Update user's display name
const updateUsername = (newName) => {
    auth.currentUser.updateProfile({
        displayName: newName
    }).then(() => {
        // Once the name has been updated, append it to the user dropdown menu
        updateDisplayNameInDOM(firebase.auth().currentUser)
    });
}
```

Comment: I can't find what `updateDisplayNameInDOM` does. Also could you share your HTML/CSS so it's easier to reproduce the issue?

Comment: Here is the updateDisplayNameInDOM function: // Show user's display name inside the DOM
const updateDisplayNameInDOM = (currentUser) => {
    document.querySelector("#user_name").innerHTML = currentUser.displayName;
}

Answer (score 1):

Can you try to remove the `updateProfileForm.reset();` from your code. It looks like this causes that the subsequent update fail.